# Ruby On Rails-Make content on show page content-editable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, contenteditable, rails7

I would like to make my show page content editable by double clicking on the content and after I update that content, then that updated content would also be save in the database. I am working on Ruby on Rails. Any suggestions, how can make my content editable.

Comment: I think without javascript it is not possible

Comment: You can make use of Jquery best_in_place https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place. This will make the field editable on click and will save it after changes

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to SO, questions that fit along the lines of "how would I do this?" without any specific code hardly ever get an answer, and when they do, the answer is likely to misunderstand your intent. Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1):

Rails 7 has [Hotwire](https://www.bootrails.com/blog/rails-7-hotwire-a-tutorial/)

This can also be accomplished with [AJAX and UJS](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/03/rails-ajax/)

Basically, when a user clicks on an area you want to be content-editable, you would replace that static section of the DOM with a form and a field. Then either clicking a submit button or clicking away would trigger a remote PATCH or PUT call to update the database and you'd again replace that section of the DOM with a static section containing the newly edited data.

There are quite a few good tutorials out there on this subject.

- https://gorails.com/episodes/inline-editing-turbo-frames
- https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/inline-editing-records
- https://bhserna.com/inline-crud-hotwire.html
- https://dev.to/mikerogers0/inline-editing-with-turboframetag-hotwire-rails-284
- https://akshaykhot.com/turbo-frames/

And even some gems for you to use:
https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_in_place_editing